# How to enable domain wide delegation to the service account of Google Drive API v3 in Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

[I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47576097/10712882) that the best way to transfer the ownership is to

1. Enable domain wide delegation to the service account
2. Impersonate the user while initialling the drive service as below:

```
using (var credentialJSON =new FileStream(_settings.CertificatePath,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var credentialParameters =
                NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<JsonCredentialParameters>(credentialJSON);

            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(credentialParameters.ClientEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes,
                    User = ownerEmailAddress, //put in the actual user email address
                }.FromPrivateKey(credentialParameters.PrivateKey));
        }
```

How can I do the same in Python? I usually create my Drive in this way:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        service_json_fp, scopes=SCOPES)

drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: [It's impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785468/10712882) to do without paid GSuite